# Select substring in Oracle SQL up to a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, nvl, instr

Let's consider the following example. Say I have a table column called N.Note and it contains the string:

Veg: Lettuce 200 ¶ Fruit: Oranges 200 ¶ Dairy: Milk 300 ¶

This string is not constant and always changes positions. I would like select 'Oranges 200' . How can I edit this line below:

SUBSTR(N.NOTE, INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:')+6, 18) as Substring

Answer (score 0):

As the string after orange ends with an ¶, you can chec for4 the position of that character after fruit comes.

as your last entry also contains and ending character

i added `LENGTH` additional so that you only need to exchange the category, the rest makes the query then automatically.

Last You can add a `TRIM`because there will be some spaces too much

> ```
> CREATE TABLE n (note varchar2(200))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO n VALUES ('Veg: Lettuce 200 ¶ Fruit: Oranges 200 ¶ Dairy: Milk 300 ¶')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTR(N.NOTE
> , INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:')+ LENGTH('Fruit:'),INSTR(N.NOTE,'¶',INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:')+ LENGTH('Fruit:'), 1) - 1 - INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:') - LENGTH('Fruit:')  ) as Substring FROM n
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTRING    |
> | :----------- |
> |  Oranges 200 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  INSTR(N.NOTE,'¶',INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:')+ LENGTH('Fruit:'), 1) - 1 - INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Fruit:') - LENGTH('Fruit:')   FROM n
> ```
>
> ```
> | INSTR(N.NOTE,'¶',INSTR(N.NOTE,'FRUIT:')+LENGTH('FRUIT:'),1)-1-INSTR(N.NOTE,'FRUIT:')-LENGTH('FRUIT:') |
> | -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                                                                     12 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTR(N.NOTE
> , INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Dairy:')+ LENGTH('Dairy:'),INSTR(N.NOTE,'¶',INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Dairy:')+ LENGTH('Dairy:'), 1) - 1 - INSTR(N.NOTE, 'Dairy:') - LENGTH('Dairy:')  ) as Substring FROM n
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTRING |
> | :-------- |
> |  Milk 300 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98192b38233ec2cebdd5a80eb62b1ab1)*

Answer (score 0):

That's, of course, wrong data model. You should normalize it and skip problems you currently have.

---

Meanwhile, suppose you'd like to select all fruits from that table. You'd then e.g. - with the following sample data -

```
SQL> with
  2  n (note) as
  3    (select 'Veg: Lettuce 200 ¶ Fruit: Oranges 200 ¶ Dairy: Milk 300 ¶' from dual union all
  4     select 'Fruit: Apples 400 ¶ Veg: Carrot 200 ¶ Dairy: Tea 100 ¶'    from dual
  5    ),
```

use such a query: split those strings into rows and fetch only what you're interested in (passed as a parameter. As this is SQL*Plus, I'm using a substitution variable. Depending on a tool you use, that might be a bind variable, `:par_what`, or something else)

```
  6  temp as
  7    (select trim(regexp_substr(note, '[^¶]+', 1, column_value)) val
  8     from n cross join
  9       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(note, '¶')
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  select trim(substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1)) result
 14  from temp
 15  where substr(val, 1, instr(val, ':') - 1) = '&par_what';
Enter value for par_what: Fruit

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------
Oranges 200
Apples 400

SQL> /
Enter value for par_what: Dairy

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------
Milk 300
Tea 100

SQL>
```